# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder::dropForeign()

Tags: php, laravel

```
class CreateCommentsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->text('comment');

            $table->boolean('approved');
            $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropForeign(['post_id']);
        Schema::dropIfExists('comments');
    }
}
```

This is what my migration class looks like, i have been trying to delete the table from the database but it throws me an error.

**Error**

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder::dropForeign()

I have gone through the documentation but it doesnot seem to be of much help.

could anyone please point out my mistake and what would be the solution ?

Just so you know , i am new to laravel.Go easy on me.Thanks!.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dropForeign` needs to be called under `Schema::table` with a `Blueprint` object,

```
Schema::table('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('comments_post_id_foreign');
    });
```

This follows the naming convention of `<table_name>_<foreign_table_name>_<column_name>_foreign`.

OR

```
Schema::table('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign(['your_key_name']);
    });
```

Comment: If you specify just key, it should be an array. Otherwise it'll not work.

Comment: Yeah, naming convention for foreign key in migration is `<table_name>_<foreign_table_name>_<column_name>_foreign`, right?

Comment: Yes. In Laravel 5 you also can use just key, but it should be inside an array, like `dropForeign(['your_key_name'])`

Comment: Please update your code so people who will find your answer in future could use correct code.

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong syntax. It should be:

```
Schema::table('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropForeign('comments_post_id_foreign');
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#foreign-key-constraints